# Ember js Query Param Alphabetical Order

Tags: javascript, ember.js, hyperlink, ember-cli, ember-query-params

I current have a link as below in xyz page i.e.
`#/xyz`:

```
<a href="#/abc/def?zqp=2&bqp=1">Random Text</a>
```

Upon clicking this I go to below url first

```
#/abc/def?zqp=2&bqp=1
```

And then the url changes to below url cause I believe ember-js takes in query params in alphbetical order

```
#/abc/def?bqp=1&zqp=2
```

Can you observe that order of query params has changed from

```
zqp=2&bqp=1 to bqp=1&zqp=2
```

I believe this is because ember js takes the query param as per alphabetical order

Now in `bqp=1&zqp=2` when I press back I dont go to xyz instead I go `zqp=2&bqp=1` with an error saying undefined route.

How to prevent this apart from re-ordering the query-params?

Note: I have not used ember link-to but have the href of link tag set directly. Cannot change this to link-to btw.

Comment: Have you defined your query params in controller? Following your logics any word would be alphabetically ordered :D?

Comment: yep defined in controller, I didn get you "any word would be alphabetically ordered"?

Comment: Query params are order-independent. Nothing in your APIs, or in Ember, depends on their order. A different order of query params could not cause an undefined route error.

Comment: you could try it in your app, let me see if i can create a JSBin. Once I rectify the order it works just fine.

Comment: What does your router look like for `abc/def`? It shouldn't have any segments in there. Are you putting your query parameters in the controller [like this](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/routing/query-params/)?

Comment: @wallop if i used for instace "?car=1" => ?acr=1

Comment: @PaulOliver I have been working on ember for quite sometime now so yes the declaration of queryParams and more are as they should be

Comment: @torazaburo it does not cause undefined route error when it is entered but while pressing back it does. I am trying to create an example. If you can run that locally you can observe the same

Comment: `bpq` changes to `bqp`?

Comment: @torazaburo sorry my bad, I corrected, I meant bqp=1&zqp=2 changes to zqp=2&bqp=1.

Comment: Is xyz not an ember.js page? Is that why you can't use link-to?

Comment: yep it is, its a dynamic for-each link I am creating in a component so this.transitionTo or link-to is not possible. I know i can still send to parent controller and do but that is not optimal. Anyway the question why this is happening since it should not